# Access minikube ingress without setting /etc/hosts

Tags: minikube

Wondering if there is anyway I can discover ingress resources on my host machine without setting a dns entry manually every time in the /etc/hosts file. I also don't want to have to run minikube tunnel or anything like that. If the vm is running on my machine and I can access the ingress with a /etc/hosts entry there should be someway to access the resource without having to go through all that trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing *minikube* k8s [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) via enforced by `minikube tunnel` command *External IP* address probably is not the good way reaching the nested application endpoints. The approach here is just to assign *External IP (origin ClusterIP)* to all K8s services exposed with type [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) as per *minikube* [Load Balancer Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/157eeeff2219afde6f085f515a5283476af6c280/docs/tunnel.md#load-balancer-controller) design.

Assuming, that you've already launched [NGINX Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller) add-on for the relevant *minikube* instance, you would be able to expose particular K8s service with type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) and point to it in the corresponded [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource as described in this [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#deploy-a-hello-world-app) from K8s tutorial pages, hence you don't need to push tunnel any longer.

According to DNS discovery method, I suppose, that adding domain name and translating it to origin IP address via `/etc/hosts` file is the most common way, considering that you don't have the particular record for this domain name across *DNS resolvers*, configured on your Linux machine.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to access services on NodePort. I want to access them through the ingress because I have special routing rules on the ingress that I want to test.

Comment: If you use `LoadBalancer` type of K8s service, there is no the other way how to achieve this without tunneling in `minikube` cliuster.

Comment: The first sentence has some grammatical errors in it.